# Mobile website not displaying images

Tags: html, image, browser, mobile

So. My mobile website doesn't display images on a mobile browser! It works fine on a computer, but not on the mobile.. I must be missing something obvious! :(

http://alltanksltd.co.uk/mobile/

Comment: No problems with the markup seems it must be the image file itself.

Can you save another file format to check - JPEG perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it seems that the logo image is a jpeg file with an png extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the file extension to jpeg. File information below confirms its actually a jpeg.

http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Falltanksltd.co.uk%2Fmobile%2Flogo.png

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much for the help folks! 

Useful tool on regex.info aswell :)